# Getting an average from a text file

Tags: python

I have scores in a txt file and have imported the name, score into a blank list. I need to know how to get an average score from the list for the txt file.

**code**

```
 column = []     
 for line in open('name,score.txt','r').readlines():
          column.append(line.strip(':'))
```

**The text file data**

```
 pon : 9
 jon : 3
 bob: 10
 zack : 4
 cam : 5
 tim : 3
```

How do I get an average from the list???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are over-complicating it guys. Just extract numbers from the file using `isdigit()`

```py
    list_ = [float(x) for x in open(FILE).read().split() if x.isdigit()]
    m = 1. *sum(list_) / len(list_)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few fixes required

```
column = []
for line in open('test.txt','r').readlines():
       column.append(line.strip().split(':')[1])  # Strip the new lines
                                                  # Split on the :
                                                  # Append the second value
column = map(int,column)                          # Convert everything to int
avg = sum(column)/len(column)                     # Find the average using sum
print (avg)                                       # Finally print it
```

Note that [Kasra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30355130/4099593)'s answer is more pythonic way to do it. I have just corrected your code.

Comment: avg = sum(column)/len(column)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'pon : 9\n'

Comment: I guess you changed `line.strip().split(':')[1]` in your code, Or the sample text file attached is not exactly matching with file on your machine. @user00

Answer (score 1):

As per the format of your text file is concerned, after splitting each line on `:` you will get a list with two values, first then name and second the marks, So you need to use `line.split(':')[1]`, The after iteration of the file is finished, you have some strings in the `column` list, to perform any arithmetic operations on the contents of the list you need to convert all those elements of the list to `int` which is done by using `map()` function.

Also If you are using Python 2.x then you explicitly need to convert either one of `sum(list)` or `len(list)` to float, Otherwise the average would always be returned as an `int`.

```
column = []
for line in open('name,score.txt','r').readlines():
    column.append(line.strip().split(':')[1])
column_int = map(int, column)
print "average = ", sum(column_int)/float(len(column_int))
```

Comment: You forgot to `strip` the newlines here

Answer (score 0):

Get all the numbers (don't forget to convert them to integers) and do this

```
x=sum(list_of_numbers)
```

Here `x` contains the sum. Then divide the sum by the length of this list.

```
for line in open('name,score.txt','r').readlines():
    column.append(int(line.split(':')[1]))
print sum(column) / len(column)
```

Comment: get an error message: NameError: name 'list_of_numbers' is not defined

Comment: @user00, <sarcasm>really?!</sarcasm> That was just an example. The actual code is at the end (it starts with `for line...`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `readlines` also as a more pythonic way for dealing with files you can use [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) and then use a generator expression within `sum` function :

```
 with open('name,score.txt','r') as f :
      s=sum(int(line.split(':')[-1]) for line in f)
      l=sum(1 for _ in f)
      avg=s/l
```

Comment: `l` is `0` hence `ZeroDivisionError` the file is at the end after the first full iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Use `float` to convert the strings to avoid integer divisison in Python 2:

```
with open('name,score.txt','r') as f :
    data = [float(line.split(':')[-1]) for line in f]
    avg = sum(data) / len(data)
```

The `with` context manager guarantees that the file will be closed.
The list comprehension `[float(line.split(':')[-1]) for line in f]` reads the last column after the `:` into a list of floats. Finally, the average is the sum of all numbers divided by the count, i.e. the length of the list.